# DockPanel Suite (C#) - How to access variables and Custom methods of Tool Window from Child Form

Tags: c#, interface, mdi, mdichild, dockpanel-suite

This look like silly and similar to previous questions but it's not.

Project details: I am using Dockpanel Suite

```
MDIParent - Form1    testapp  
MDIChild  - Form2  child window  
ToolWindow - Form3  toolwindow  / logs
```

[Snapshot of Test App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCg9Q.png)

I want to access `ToolWindow` (logs window) procedures and variables from form2 (child window):

```
public partial class Form2 : DockContent, IForm2
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string m_fileName = "This is Private";

    public string _FileName()
    {
        return this.m_fileName;
    }
}

interface IForm2
{
    string _FileName();
}
```

and I am calling procedures of `Form2` from `ToolWindow` using this code:

```
if (DockPanel.FindForm().ActiveMdiChild != null)
{
    IForm2 childForm = (IForm2)DockPanel.FindForm().ActiveMdiChild;
    MessageBox.Show(childForm._FileName() );
}
```

Now I want to do the same in reverse: I want to access data and procedures of `ToolWindow` (logs) from child window.

Found this link [Dockpanel Suite and passing data across multiple forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16528931/dockpanel-suite-and-passing-data-across-multiple-forms) but not working for me. My scenario is a different one.

Comment: You could instantiate all the forms in the Program.cs Class, make them public and access the data from the forms there like `Program.form2.Text`

Comment: not working in DockPanel Suite. i tried it. look at my code once. it works when i want to access data on child forms. but not when i am trying to access data from tool window from child window.

Comment: Thanks for Response

Comment: Found Solution on Microsoft Forum


var iForm3= Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form3>().Single();   


iForm3.MethodOnForm3();

Comment: @MediaHub you should post your finding as an answer and accept it.

Comment: iForm3= Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form3>().Single(); iForm3.MethodOnForm3();

Comment: this was the solution for my problem.